# iframe scrolling on the iphone

Tags: iphone, iframe, scroll

I was aware of multiple scrolling libraries (TouchScroll, iScroll) for the iPhone/iOS due to its inability (???) to support overflow:scroll . However, I was not aware (and I am looking for confirmation) that IFRAMEs don't really work either. It appears that the iframe doesn't respect any attempt to give it a fixed size and always just resizes itself to its content. Am I correct on this? Is the only way to scroll an IFRAME to place it inside a block element with the overflow CSS property set and then to use a lib like the aforementioned?

Comment: I have tried without success to achieve a scrolling iframe on the iPhone, and also found that the iframe ignores any attempt to set its size. You mention placing the iframe within a block element in combination with a scrolling library - did this work for you as a workaround? I've had no success with any approach so far.

Comment: James, is it still the case that you "have tried without success to achieve a scrolling iframe on the iPhone"?   I've been experimenting and googling for solutions, also without success.  (Note: an iframe by itself does work, but not once I combine it with iscroll/touchscroll/etc)

Answer (score 8):

simply adding...

```
overflow-y:auto; 
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
```

to a div around my iframe worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll any content which is set to overflow:auto by ***touching with two fingers and dragging***.  Don't put iFrame inside a div with overflow:auto, and instead set the iframe to overflow:auto itself.  Unfortunately, iframe scrolling is *very* choppy, regardless of content or device, so the best solution is to find a way to make your content fit into one long page, with "top" & "bottom" view divs set to follow the viewport (if this is the effect you're going for.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you given Joe Hewitt's Scrollability library a go?

You can read more about it here:

[Scrollability, New iOS Physics Project from Facebook for iPhone Creator, Joe Hewitt](http://www.readwriteweb.com/mobile/2011/05/joe-hewitt-creator-of-facebook-for-iphone-reveals-new-project-scrollability.php)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me (thanks to Christopher Zimmermann for his blog post http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/blog/2012/05/strategies-for-the-iframe-on-the-ipad-problem/). The problems are:
1. There are no scroll bars to let the user know that they can scroll
2. Users have to use two-finger scrolling
3. The PDF files are not centered (still working on it)

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Testing iFrames on iPad</title>
      <style>
      div {
        border: solid 1px green;
        height:100px;
      }

    .scroller{
        border:solid 1px #66AA66;
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
        overflow: auto;
        text-align:center;

    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="scroller">
        <iframe width="400" height="400" src="http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/11pdf/11-393c3a2.pdf" ></iframe>
    </div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="scroller">
        <iframe width="400" height="400" src="http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/11pdf/11-393c3a2.pdf" ></iframe>
    </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><div class="scroller">
        <iframe width="400" height="400" src="http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/11pdf/11-393c3a2.pdf" ></iframe>
    </div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="scroller">
        <iframe width="400" height="400" src="http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/11pdf/11-393c3a2.pdf" ></iframe>
    </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div> Here are some additional contents.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -4):

Flippant answer: don't use IFRAMES anymore.